# How to handle Jmeter's Post request passing JSON parameter number value in single digits with " "

Tags: json, regex, jmeter, correlation

I have a variable extracted as the number "235839", It is passing as it is with most of the post requests json body parameters.
But some of the requests are passing just this number but in the format like -

> Parameter Name - json

> Value - {"header_ids":["2","3","5","8","3","9"]}

How do I get individual digits from the extracted variable number?
I have tried extracting single digits using regular expression using syntax (\d), but it doesn't work for single-digit extract.

Please assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

```
${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([header_ids: vars.get('foo').collect()]).toPrettyString(),)}
```

replace `foo` with your [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) name holding your `235839` value

More information:

- [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: You are a real champ. The solution provided is working exactly the same.